# What does it mean to "nucleate multi-protein complexes"?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-signaling

I am reading [an article](https://jcs.biologists.org/content/122/20/3589) about the mTOR signalling pathway and I have come across the following:

> mTOR nucleates at least two distinct multi-protein complexes, mTOR
> complex 1 (mTORC1) and mTOR complex 2 (mTORC2).

I am not sure what is meant by "mTOR nucleates 2 multi-protein complexes". From the paper, I understand that mTOR is a component of the mTORC1 and mTORC2 complexes. I have read the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nucleate) of 'nucleate' online and it means to either "to form into a cluster" or "to act as a nucleus for". However in the context of this article, I am not clear about what is meant by "nucleates" in the above statement. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here [nucleation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleation) has a rather physical meaning. mTOR acts as the starting assembly point of the complex.